# How to get around "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025."?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-4.3

I am using the Entity Framework 4.3, POCO, database first and I am getting the following error:

**Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.**

QUESTION:  *I think that my query expresses my intent but I seem to be hitting this error, so I am wondering if anyone knows how I could structure my query differently to get around this error?*

Here is the scenario...

I have a SQL server 2008 database that has 2 tables - A and B:

**A**

- AId (int - not null - identity - primary key)
- AName (nvarchar(10) - not null)

**B**

- BId (int - not null - identity - primary key)
- SomeName (nvarchar(10) - not null)
- AId (int - not null - foreign key connecting to AId in the table A)

I then define the context like so:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        As = Set<A>();
        Bs = Set<B>();
    }

    public DbSet<A> As { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; private set; }
}
```

And the entity classes like so:

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; private set; }

    public void AddB(B b)
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        }

        if (Bs == null)
        {
            Bs = new List<B>();
        }

        if (!Bs.Contains(b))
        {
            Bs.Add(b);
        }

        b.A = this;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public string SomeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now for the query...

What I want is all of the As where every "B SomeName" is in the list of names supplied so I do this:

```
var names = new[] {"Name1", "Name2"};

var ctx = new DatabaseContext("EFPlayingEntities");
var res = ctx.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.SomeName).All(names.Contains));

// Here I evaluate the query and I get:
//   Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.
Console.WriteLine(res.Count());
```

To be clear about what I mean, if the table data looks like this:

```
AId,AName
1,A1
2,A2
3,A3
4,A4

BId,SomeName,AId
1,Name1,1
2,Name2,1
3,Name1,2
4,Name1,3
5,Name3,3
6,Name1,4
7,Name2,4
```

I would expect to get back A1, A2 and A4 (so that count call above would return 3).

Comment: did you look into inner exception?

Comment: The inner exception is null :-(

Comment: names.Contains is not valid code, not sure how that compiles.  I suspect you want to use Intersect() instead of All().

Comment: @Hans, sorry but it is valid code and it compiles fine.  It is equivalent to "All(b => names.Contains(b))".  Intersect returns a set and I need a boolean at this point, hence All

Comment: @user1039947: It is not equivalent, posted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why this happens is subtle.

`Queryable.All` need to be called with an `Expression`. Passing in just the method 'reference' creates a delegate, and subsequently, `Enumerable.All` becomes the candidate instead of the intended `Queryable.All`.

This is why your solution you posted as an answer works correctly.

**EDIT**

so if you write the statement as this, it will work without exception:

```
var res = ctx.As.Where(
  a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.SomeName).All(b => names.Contains(b)));
```

Comment: Woah!  So even though .All(b => names.Contains(b)) is functionally (I mean in terms of what it does, not how it does it) equivalent to .All(names.Contains) what you are saying is the underlying mechanism is different and I hit upon a bug in the EF when it is evaluating the expression tree?  I just tried it and this "ctx.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.SomeName).All(b => names.Contains(b)))" does in fact execute without error!  Thank you!

Comment: I hope you do not mind, I added a bit to your answer so that if anyone else comes across this they will see straight away the change you suggested.

Comment: @user1039947: No problem :) This is not an EF bug, but rather a missing feature with C#'s expression compiler.

Comment: I just put a bounty on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990158/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1025)... wanna grab it?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out a solution to this, in case anyone is interested.  Doing the following is equivalent and does not result in the exception in the question:

```
var res = ctx
    .Bs
    .GroupBy(b => b.A)
    .Where(g => g.All(b => names.Contains(b.SomeName)))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

I do not know if this is the best way though!?

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of your query look good to me; clearly, getting an internal provider error is not the intended behaviour! I would have expected some more explicit mesage about EF not being able to translate your query into a store operation, if that's in fact what the problem is.

Another way to do what you want would be:

```
var names = new[] {"Name1", "Name2"};
var nameCount = names.Length;

var ctx = new DatabaseContext("EFPlayingEntities");
var result = ctx.As
    .Where(a => a.Bs
                 .Select(b => b.SomeName)
                 .Intersect(names)
                 .Count() == a.Bs.Count());
```

(get every `A` such that intersecting its `B`s' names with the fixed list gives all the `B`s)

although I haven't tried this to see if EF can translate *this* successfully.

Another way:

```
var names = new[] {"Name1", "Name2"};

var ctx = new DatabaseContext("EFPlayingEntities");
var result = ctx.As
    .Where(a => !a.Bs.Select(b => b.SomeName).Except(names).Any());
```

(get every `A` such that the list of its `B`s' names is reduced to nothing by taking out the fixed list)

also untried.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer and both execute fine without exception!  However, neither of your solutions quite match the functionality as I need it to also return any A that has a collection of Bs with a subset of the collection of names I pass in.  In my example data I would expect A2 to also be returned since it has "Name1" inside it.

Comment: By the way, if you create a fake "Context" class where the As collection is a List<A> and then the query I have in the question works fine and returns what I expect.  I have come up with a way to do the equivalent functionality (see my answer) that does work but I am not sure it is the best way (it may be the only way as this feels like a bug in Entity Framework to me).

Comment: @user oops, had the subsetting the wrong way round; updated my answer. I think the `Except` way is definitely the better of the two now. And yes, all of: your original, your answer, and my two ways, all have the same semantics - which to choose is purely a matter of taste and of course whether EF can successfully translate...